# do Spambots ignore javascript?

Tags: javascript, spam-prevention, spam, bots

My website's registration page was getting hammered by spambots to the tune of 1 fake registration attempts a day (hammered relative to my overall traffic! ha).

As registration fires off confirmation emails, I wanted to lock this down if possible.

I went ahead and implemented the hidden form input screen (address, phone, etc) and now my site automatically redirects to spambot.php if the "sensors" are tripped.

**This has been working great...**

but I'm curious about the after effects. I've got my Google Analytics javascript nugget in the spambot.php page, but it has only registered 1 pageview in the past month. Meanwhile, my host's AWStats logs indicate 19 pageviews -- which would seem about right considering past history.

Which makes me wonder - do spambots generally ignore javascript?

Comment: Most used not to parse and execute JS; it is to be expected that less and less will in order to more believably simulate a browser. Not sure whether a generic answer can be given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is an extremely difficult question to answer, I will just give my own, subjective opinion:

**No**, most of them probably don't.

I cannot prove that this is true - but another, similar question that I often see is whether Googlebot ignores JavaScript or not - and [it could seem that it doesn't](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html).

Google (maybe) discards most JavaScript due to performance reasons - and as Googlebot and a spambot performs the same task - crawls the web - I don't think that most spambots would run JavaScript.